# Python : Using csv.writer where some values can contain ","

Tags: python, csv

I am using `csv.writer` to write to a csv.

```
csv_writer = csv.writer( f , quotechar = '"' ,  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL )
csv_writer.writerow( header )

for row in rows :
   csv_writer.writerow([ row["value1"], row["value2"],row["value3"] ] )
```

But some of my value2 are like this **Name,withcomma**

So in these rows I end up with 4 columns.

I tried changing to :

```
csv_writer = csv.writer( f , quotechar = '"' , delimiter = "|",  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL )
```

or a character that I will not exist on the data like `chr(255)` but this messed up my data completely.

Any ideas?

**Update:**

by 4 columns I mean that for the rows with that value I see:

```
column 2 : "Name
column 3 : withcomma"
```

Instead of a single column `"Name,withcomma`" ( and column 3 is shifted to column 4 )

Comment: What makes you say "*I end up with 4 columns*"? Did you open the resulting file with some computer program? What program? Precisely what did you see?

Comment: @Robᵩ updated - please check

Comment: Have you tried saving it as a tsv instead? use `\t` as a delimiter?

Comment: What program displays `"column 2 : "Name`?

Comment: Your `for` loop doesn't make any sense. Did you mean `csv_writer.writerow([ row["value1"], row["value2"],row["value3"])`?

Comment: @Robᵩ I open it with excel. ( I mean I open with excel and I see 4 columns instead of 3 )

Comment: @pault yes I fixed that, that's what I mean

Comment: Thanks for mentioning which program you use to open the file. CSV is not a single, universal standard; each program implements it indifferent ways. The default dialect of the `csv` module is "excel", but you are changing some of the parameters from their defaults. What happens when you try just `csv_writer = csv.writer(f)` with no other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `csv.writer([ row["value1"], row["value2"],row["value3"] ] )` line is not a typo, it shouldn't even be working as you should be referencing back to your `csv_writer` object.  Try using `csv_writer.writerow()` instead

```
import csv
headers = ["col1", "col2", "col3"]
rows=[
    {"value1": "abc", "value2": "def", "value3": "FN,LN"},
    {"value1": "ghi", "value2": "jkl", "value3": "SN"}
]

with open('test.csv','w') as file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(file,lineterminator="\n", quotechar = '"' ,  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    csv_writer.writerow(headers)
    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow([row["value1"],row["value2"],row["value3"]])
```

**Output:**

```
"col1","col2","col3"
"abc","def","FN,LN"
"ghi","jkl","SN"
```

Comment: yeap but that's correct and if I do `less` on the file I can see that. But when I open it with excel, it doesn't care about the , inside the "", it will just show it as a new column. Is it an excel problem then?

Comment: When I open on my excel it was fine.  I have a feeling it might be your Excel.  Have you tried opening the csv file on a different spreadsheet program e.g. Google Sheets? If you copied my output and save it as a csv to open on Excel, does it still show FN/LN as two separate columns?

Answer (score 0):

Actually your sample code `csv.writer([ row["value1"], row["value2"],row["value3"]])` (added the missing trailing bracket `]`) raises a TypeError. See https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.writer

From the way you handle your `rows`variable I assume it to be a list of dicts... if this data is prepared correctly, there should be no problems. Here is a working example code

```
import csv
rows = [
    {"value1": "ab", "value2": "cd", "value3": "ef"},
    {"value1": "a,b", "value2": "cd", "value3": "ef"},
]
header = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name3"]
with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(f , quotechar = '"' ,  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL )
    csv_writer.writerow( header )

    for row in rows:
        csv_writer.writerow([row["value1"], row["value2"], row["value3"]])
```

This gives the output

```
"Name1","Name2","Name3"
"ab","cd","ef"
"a,b","cd","ef"
```

Comment: yeap but that's correct and if I do 'less' on the file I can see that. But when I open it with excel, it doesn't care about the , inside the "", it will just show it as a new column. Is it an excel problem then?

Comment: Might be an Excel issue. What Locale do you have? Maybe Excel's default expectation on the csv-separator is ";" instead of ",".
Try `csv_writer = csv.writer(f , quotechar = '"' ,  quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL , delimiter=";")`